# Add icon to button with custom style

Tags: android, xml

I have a button which defined like below:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/my_style"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_register_fab"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    />
```

**my_style.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="oval"
>
<solid android:color="@color/path_primary"/>
<stroke
  android:width="2dp"
  android:color="@color/white"
  />
</shape>
```

when i want to add an icon to my button putting `android:src="..."` doesn't work neither in the main_activity.xml nor in my_style.xml

How can i set an icon for my button?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A button can´t have an image. For this exists the class ImageButton.

The code will look exactly as you wrote, you just need to change the class to ImageButton

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/my_style"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_register_fab"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    />
```

Here you have the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) and here and [example](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-example/)